# Randomly Partition versus Partition then Shuffle

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, theory

Given a set of n data points generated from the same distribution, I want to "randomly partition" the set into k groups, where each contains n / k points randomly chosen from the original data set.

Alternatively, I can first divide the input data set into k contiguous chunks, where the first chunk contains 1, ..., n/k, and the second chunk contains n/k+1, ..., 2n/k, and so on. Then I "shuffle" the data points within each partition.

Are these two approaches always equal, given the data set are generated from the same distribution? If not, what assumptions do we need when these two approaches produces the same results?

Comment: So the data points are random numbers (or other data)?  If they're [independent and identically distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables), then everything you want will be true (and shuffling will be unnecessary).  If they aren't,things get more complicated.

Comment: @Teepeemm I just checked the definition of "independent and identically distributed", and it seems to be what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously they are not equivalent; the second restricts the values that can go in each partition, while the first does not.

If by "results" you mean what is *done* with these partitions, that would be wholly dependent on just what that is, which you provide no hint to.

Comment: I want to train an ensemble of classifiers on the partitions/groups of the data. So my question is, if I train two ensembles of classifiers using these different partition techniques, do they have the same power on predicting the data? One of the possible assumption we need is that the data comes from a stationary data generating process, such that in the second method, each partition can represent the demographic of the entire data set.

Comment: If one method has more flexibility in what the resulting partitions can be than the other, then unless there are assumptions that prevent that flexibility from being exercised, I don't see how the two methods can produce the same results.  Your own example assumption suggests the second method can represent information the first cannot, which presumably could be used in the overall application.